# Android camera control how long captured image stays in preview after shutter

Tags: android, android-camera

I am taking a picture in Android (2.3 and greater) that takes a picture using `camera.takePicture()`. It works great, but I get weird behavior on different devices. On my Nexus One, the image I captured stays frozen for a few seconds before reverting to the preview. On my Transformer, it reverts to the preview almost immediately.

For now, a workaround would be to call `camera.stopPreview()` in the `onShutter()` event, but that's still a bit weird, since it's not showing the photo you took, it's showing what the preview saw a split second after you took the picture. On the Transformer, you can even see it "freeze-move-freeze" as it freezes for a split second after taking the picture, starts moving again, then gets to onShutter and freezes when I call `stopPreview()`.

Does anyone know of a setting somewhere, or some code I could call, that would tell the camera how long to hold onto that image before restarting the preview? Or better yet, have it not automatically release the preview at all, and wait until I call startPreview?

Answer (score 1):

on my devices I have to restart the preview manually, it doesn't start up itself after taking a picture. I use a picture callback like

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, takePictureCallback);
```

and the callback is

```
private Camera.PictureCallback takePictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera cam) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (camera != null) {
                    camera.startPreview();
                }

                canTakePicture = true;
            }
        }, PHOTO_PREVIEW_LENGTH);

        new PhotoProcessor(activity, targetUri).execute(data);
    }
};
```

PhotoProcessor saves the image, PHOTO_PREVIEW_LENGTH is the length in ms for how long is the captured image shown.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. This seems like a good approach, but the project I was working on is long dead and I'm not sure I could test this even if I wanted to.

Comment: ah damn, I didnt notice its that old question :D nevermind then